# How to control automagically appearing indeterminate progress circle

Tags: android, android-progressbar, rx-java

In `MainActivity.onStart()` of my app, it gets data from a RESTful service, populates a local SQLite db with data from the service, then populates a View with that data. Using RxJava, the functionality that calls the RESTful service and populates the SQLite is made to be the observable and the fragment containing the View uses RxJava to subscribe to this. When it is done, the View is notified and gets the data from the SQLite db.  During this process, a progress circle appears (automatically, I've added no progress bar code myself). When the View has been populated, the circle is no
longer displayed. All is well.

When the device is turned from Portrait -> Landscape (or vice-versa), my code recognizes this and skips the RESTful service and, using a similar observer/subscriber mechanism, gets data from the SQLite db and populates the View. The progress circle is displayed again here but, this is the problem, it keeps spinning and never goes away, though the app continues to function normally.

What is causing this progress circle to appear? How can I control it?

First observer/subscriber:

```
MyListFragment myListFragment = (MyListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_main_tag));
mLoadAndStoreDataObservable = Observable.create(
   new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
         @Override
         public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

             try {
                 Utilities.loadAndStoreData(mActivity); // call RESTful service, populate SQLite
                 subscriber.onNext("Utilities.loadAndStoreData Done");
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
             subscriber.onError(e);
             }
         }
       }
     )
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(myListFragment);
```

Observer/subscriber when device is rotated:

```
MyListFragment myListFragment = (MyListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_main_tag));
mLoadAndStoreDataObservable = Observable.create(
   new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
         @Override
         public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

             try {
                // don't call restful service,  Just tell observer that data is available in SQLite
                subscriber.onNext("Utilities.loadAndStoreData Done");
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
             subscriber.onError(e);
             }
         }
       }
     )
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(myListFragment);
```

MyListFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(null); // see if this prevents progress circle ... nope
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onNext(String s) {
    // SQLite is populated now, so display the data in the list view
    ArrayList<MyListData> myListDataList = Utilities.getDataFromSQLite(getActivity());
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myListDataList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The device I am testing with is a (1st gen) Nexus 7, Android 4.2.2 and a (2nd gen) Nexus 7, Android 4.4.4

**Answer**:
LordRaydenMK suggests that the default ListView implementation shows a spinner when the list doesn't have an adapter set
This indeed appears to be the case. Setting the adapter like below causes the progress circle not to appear

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Waiting for data ..." }; // never see this but whatever
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity() .getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter); // see if this prevents progress circle ... yep
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Your `MyListFragment` extends just the plain Android `Fragment`? Or are you using any custom components? Also, where does the progress circle appear? Did you implement `onError` in your `MyListFragment` so you wouldn't silently ignore any errors?

Comment: `MyListFragment` extends `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` The progress circle appears center screen. `onError` does not get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be of much help without the code from `MyListFragment`. However I can (try) to point you in the right direction.

The default `ListView` implementation shows a spinner when the list doesn't have an adapter set. Are you sure you are setting the adapter? Are you using `setListAdapter` to set the adapter?

Also I would like to recommend a different approach when using RxJava with multiple data sources. Check out [this blog post](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) by Dan Lew. It uses the `concat()` and `first()` operators to find the best source for your data.

```
// Our sources (left as an exercise for the reader)
Observable<Data> memory = ...;  
Observable<Data> disk = ...;  
Observable<Data> network = ...;

// Retrieve the first source with data
Observable<Data> source = Observable  
  .concat(memory, disk, network)
  .first();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added code to the original post to show the call to `setListAdapter` You say that the default `Listview` implementation shows a spinner when the list doesn't have an adapter set. As my code example shows, I do set the adapter, but not until `onNext()`. I wonder if the gap between creating the fragment and calling `onNext()`, which can be 5 or 6 seconds, causes the spinner to appear.

Comment: @AlLelopath Let's make sure `onNext` is called on the main thread. You can add a log statement and check if `Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()`

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I didn't know to do that. And yes, it is indeed the main thread.

Comment: @AlLelopath both when you first start it and when you rotate the device? Is `onNext` called when you rotate the device?

Comment: Yes on start, yes on rotate.